# How to pass a URL to a collection in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I need to build several collections in Backbone that only differ by their URL.  Here is my model:

```
App.Models.Main = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

Here is my collection:

```
App.Collections.Mains = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: App.Models.Main,
        initialize: function() {
            this.fetch({
                success: function(data) {
                    //console.log(data.models);
                }
            });
        },
    url: this.url
});
```

In my router, I tried:

```
mc = new App.Collections.Mains({ url: 'main-contact'});
mains = new App.Views.Mains({ collection: mc});
$('#web-leads').append(mains.el);
```

But I get an this error: `Error: A "url" property or function must be specified`

How do I pass the URL into the collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, it's a bit ugly though:

```
 mc = new (App.Collections.Mains.extend({ url: 'main-contact'}));
 mains = new App.Views.Mains({ collection: mc});
```

You basically extend your base collection and call a new on it. Unwrapping it would be something like:

```
MainContantCollection = App.Collections.Mains.extend({ url: 'main-contact'});
mc = new MainContactCollection();
mains = new App.Views.Mains({ collection: mc});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Backbone.Collection` constructor looks like this:

```
Backbone.Collection = function(models, options) { ...
```

It expects the options as a second argument. The first argument is a list of models with which  to initialize the collection.

You need to initialize the collection with:

```
mc = new App.Collections.Mains(null, { url: 'main-contact'})
```

Also, when you're defining your collection you're not setting the `url` property correctly. The  expression `this.url` is evaluated when your model is defined, not when it is initialized. The context of `this` does not point to any instance of the collection, but the scope at the time of defining the model, probably `window`. Javascript allows you to try to set it to `window.url`, but because `window` has no such property, it's set to `undefined`.

Instead of:

```
App.Collections.Mains = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   url: this.url
});
```

You need to set the url in the `initialize` method:

```
App.Collections.Mains = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(models, options) {
       if(options && options.url) {
           this.url = options.url;
       }   
    }
});
```

Comment: I still get the same error.  Do I need to do something other than `url: this.url` in my collection?

Comment: @sehummel, oopsy, missed that. Edited my answer.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks, fencliff.

Comment: @sehummel ... I made a minor edit in my post, but nothing that should change anything. Are you sure you're passing the correct arguments: `new App.Collections.Mains(null, { url: 'main-contact' });` ?